# Inferring the user intention from the event stream in an event store. Is this even a correct thing to do?

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

We are using an event store that stores a single aggregate - a user's order (imagine an Amazon order than can be updated at any moment by both a client or someone in the e-commerce company before it actually gets dispatched).

For the first time we're going to allow our company's employees to see the order's history, as until now they could only see its current state.

We are now realizing that the events that form up the aggregate root don't really show the intent or what the user actually did. They only serve to build the current state of the order when applied sequencially to an empty order. The question is: should they?

1. Imagine a user that initially had one copy of book X and then removed it and added 2 again. Should we consider this as an event "User added 1 book" or events "User removed 1 book" + "User added 2 books" (we seem to have followed this approach)?
2. In some cases we have one initial event that then is followed by other events. I, developer, know for sure that all these events were triggered by a single command, but it seems incredibly brittle for me to make that kind of assumptions when generating on the fly this "order history" functionality for the user to see. But if I don't treat them, at least in the order history feature as a single action, it will seem like there were lots of order amendments when in fact there was just one, big one.

Should I have "macro" events that contain "micro events" inside? Should I just attach the command's id to the event so I can then easily inferr what event happened at the same and which ones not (an alternative would be relying on timestamps.. but that's disgusting).

What's the standard approch to deal with this kind of situations? I would like to be able to look at any time to the aggregate's history and generate this report (I don't want to build the report incrementally every time the order is updated).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Command names should ideally be descriptive of intent. Which should mean it's possible to create event names which make the original intent clear. As a rule of thumb, the events in the event stream should be understandable to the relevant members of the business. It's a good rule of thumb. It should contain stuff like 'cartUpdated' etc.

Given the above, I would have expected that the showing the event stream should be fine. But I totally get why it may not be ideal in some circumstances. I.e. it may be too detailed. In which case maybe create a 'summeriser' read model fed the events.

Answer (score 1):

It is common to include the command’s ID in the resulting events’ metadata, along with an optional correlation ID (useful for long running processes). This then makes it easier to build the order history projection. Alternatively, you could just use the event time stamps to correlate batches in whatever way you want (perhaps you might only want one entry even for multiple commands, if they happened in a short window).

Answer (score 1):

Events (past tense) do not always capture human - or system - user intent. Commands (imperative mood) do. As all command data cannot always be easily retraced from the events it generated, keeping a structured log of commands looks like a good option here.